# tensorflow gather then reduce_sum

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

Let's say I have a matrix `M` of size 10x5, and a set of indices `ix` of size 4x3. I want to do `tf.reduce_sum(tf.gather(M,ix),axis=1)` which would give me a result of size 4x5. However, to do this, it creates an intermediate gather matrix of size 4x3x5. While at these small sizes this isn't a problem, if these sizes grow large enough, I get an OOM error. However, since I'm simply doing a sum over the 1st dimension, I never need to calculate the full matrix. So my question is, is there a way to calculate the end 4x5 matrix without going through the intermediate 4x3x5 matrix?

Comment: Can you describe the size of your two matrix? Is the matrix that you mean large  enough `M` or `ix`?

Comment: I am mainly concerned about the size of `M`.

Comment: I can't give a solution because the  scenario and data are not specific enough. But maybe you can refer to [`tf.sparse.SparseTensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/SparseTensor?version=stable).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just multiply by sparse matrix -- I was searching if the two are internally equivalent then I landed on your post